# How to use two WebView to use SystemWebViewEngine in cordova 5.1.1

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I have an `Activity` that extends `CordovaActivity`,and then, I have two `SystemWebView` components in one `Activty`.In activity, `CordovaActivity` allows one `webView` to use `SystemWebViewEngine`.I want to use both, `SystemWebView`, and `SystemWebViewEngine`. Below code is one `webView` and make it to use `SystemWebviewEngine`.How can I do for both?

```
public class TestCordovaWithLayoutActivity extends CordovaActivity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_cordova_with_layout);
        super.init();
        // Load your application
        // launchUrl = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html"
        launchUrl = "file:///android_asset/www/index2.html";
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

    @Override
    protected CordovaWebView makeWebView() {
        SystemWebView webView = (SystemWebView)findViewById(R.id.cordovaWebView);
        return new CordovaWebViewImpl(new SystemWebViewEngine(webView));
    }

    @Override
    protected void createViews() {

        if (preferences.contains("BackgroundColor")) {
            int backgroundColor = preferences.getInteger("BackgroundColor", Color.BLACK);
            // Background of activity:
            appView.getView().setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        }

        appView.getView().requestFocusFromTouch();
    }

}
```